# help with geometrically complex analysis problem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Hello I am given Re(az+b)>0 where z=x+yi and a,b are real and the solution my prof gives is an open half plane, I dont understand how this can be. please help.

Comment: Are you given in the problem that $a,b$ are real numbers? [I assume $a \neq 0$ otherwise it's not a half-plane.]

Comment: @coffeemath a, b are real numbers

Answer (score 1):

You have $az+b=a(x+iy)+b=(ax+b)+i(ay)$ so real part is $ax+b,$ then setting real part greater than zero is $x>-b/a$ which is a half plane with vertical boundary at the line $x=-b/a$ in the complex plane.